# При изменении размера с помощью иконки resize одной mdi формы, меняются размеры остальных, как избежать подобного поведения?

Tags: delphi

Есть mdi формы в приложении. Если я на одной форме разворачиваю или сворачиваю окно, то вместе с ней разворачиваются и сворачиваются также и другие mdi окна, как изменить подобное поведение?

Comment: не использовать MDI-окна?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Вот я создал MDI-Application, вроде бы все Child окна способны жить своей жизнью.